# C++ Problem with CPR GET request in dll at exxecution time in

Tags: c++, httprequest

I have a custom CSP dll that has to make a GET request to an API. I am making the request with CPR library, but when I make this call the program hangs.

```
auto r = cpr::Get(cpr::Url{ URL });
```

I am testing with a console application loading the library and calling to the exported method.

I´m developing with Visual Studio dll project and I collect the dependencies from vcpkg.

If I make this call from the console application it works, but when I make the request from the DLL it hangs and connection is never done.

I have been trying other libraries for making the request and all of them hang when I try to make the call to the endpoint.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

If I make the request in a console application like this it works

```
BOOL Authenticate() {

    auto r = cpr::Get(cpr::Url{ URL });

    long sc = r.status_code;
    if (sc != 200) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;

}


int main()
{
    if (Authenticate()) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }

}
```

The problem is that if I make the request to the same method exported from a dll it hangs when the GET request is done. The dll is compiled with Visual Studio -> dll project. Sample here, where method authenticate is a is in previous example.

```
int main()
{
    HINSTANCE hinstDLL;
    hinstDLL = LoadLibrary(PATH_TO_DLL);
    if (!hinstDLL)
        printf("LoadLibrary error %x\n", GetLastError()); 
    else {
        Authenticate_DLL lpproc;
        lpproc = (CPAcquireContext_DLL)GetProcAddress(hinstDLL, "Authenticate");
        if (!lpproc())
        {
            printf("LoadMethod error %x\n", GetLastError());
        }

    }

}
```

URL is a REST API and in remote server no request is done, so CPR is not making the call

EDIT2:

After a lot of testing requests only hang when I make use of HTTPS URLs. If the URL is just HTTP the request is done

Comment: Please post a [minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Original post edited with sample